# Reference about the backward heat flow on closed manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes

On the paper: Bruce Kleiner, John Lott, Notes on Perelman's papers,
Geom. Topol. 12(5): 2587-2855 (2008). DOI: 10.2140/gt.2008.12.2587

The authors wrote the following statement:

[image]

(Here $-\Delta$ is the semi-posiitve Laplacian operator.)

It seems that  on closed Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$, for any compact interval $[a,b]$, with an initial function $u(b)$, we can always solve the backward heat flow
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=-\Delta u+Ru,$$
where $R$ is a smooth function.

**Q**
Can anyone give a reference about the existence  (uniqueness) about  the above  backward heat flow?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you reverse in time and take an initial datum $u(b)$, it just becomes a standard heat equation, no?

Comment: @LeoMoos Thanks for the comments. Actually, I want to emphasis that on any compact interval $[a,b]$, we can find a solution with any initial data. Do you know the reference about this?

Comment: What I meant is that reversing the time for a *backward* heat equation yields a *forward* equation. You're working on a closed manifold, so the usual estimates for parabolic PDE would yield long-time existence of your solution.